# Question about the unit disk in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z\colon |z|<1\}$ (the  unit disk ) and let $w$ be complex number. Consider the function $F:D \mapsto \mathbb C$ defined by $F(z)= (w-z)/(1- \bar wz)$. Prove that if $|w| < 1$ then $F(D) \subset D$. I feel like i can work this problem i just need an idea of how to think about it.

Comment: You need to show  that $|F(z)| < 1$ if $|\omega| <1$.. Where exactly do you have problems?

Answer (score 1):

Try calculating the modulus of $F$. In this manner $$|F(z)|=\bigg|\frac{(w-z)}{(1-\bar{w}z)}\bigg|=\frac{|w-z|}{|1-\bar{w}z|}\leq \frac{|w|+|-z|}{|1-\bar{w}z|}$$

and then use the definition of $z$ and continue simplifying.

Comment: i did that then in the end i have $|F(z)$ < 1 would that implies that $F(D) \subset D$ that is one of the reason why i post this question

Comment: @user146269 Yes. Just name $F(z)=a$. Now consider the $a$-plane and the unit disk in the $a$-plane. i.e., the set $\{a\in\mathbb{C}||a|<1\}$. Since $|F(z)|=|a|<1$, we have $F(z)$ is an element of the unit disk. If this is confusing, it is because we are essentially using two different complex planes, but they are isomorphic to one another. So $F(D)\not\subset D$, but $F(D)$ is contained in the unit disk of the codomain. This problem abuses notation a bit.

Comment: yeah i know i kept abusing the notations.

Answer (score 1):

$|F(z)|<1$ is equivalent to $|w-z|<|1-\bar wz|$, or squaring that,
$$|w|^2+|z|^2-2\operatorname{Re}(\bar wz)< 1+|w|^2|z|^2-2\operatorname{Re}(\bar wz).$$
Now you are left with proving an inequality of the form $a+b\le1+ab$ where $0\le a<1$ and $0\le b<1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

Extend the definition of $F$ to $\bar D$. Prove that $|1-\bar wz|>0$. Deduce that $F$ is holomorphic in $D$ and continuous in $\bar D$.

Suppose for the moment that $|z|=1$. Let $w=r(\cos t+i\sin t)$ and $z=\cos s+i\sin s$. Prove that $|F(z)|=1$.

Note that $F(w)=0$, so $F$ is not constant in $\bar D$.

Apply the maximum modulus principle.